# Count of 5 Digit numbers.

Tags: combinatorics

How many 5 digit numbers are there such that sum of their digits is even.

First I thought when is the sum of 5 Digits is even.  Well there are a lot of possible ways. But obviously there are less ways that sum is odd. So I decided to subtract from 
$$9*10^4$$ which is all 5 digit numbers,  the count of odd ones.
But how do I get count of the all odd ones?

Any Idea? Or maybe a better solution?

Comment: @KeyFlex yes its a duplicate. What should I do?

Comment: Try to refer to those answers.

Comment: @KeyFlex I mean should I  delete my question or what?

Comment: If the answers of the duplicate question answers your doubts then you may delete your question.